# Деактивация кнопки при незаполненных полях

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть два `input`. Если они пустые, то кнопка имеет параметр `disabled`. Если не пустые, то кнопка `enabled`.

```
<input type="text" name="fio" class="order_input" id="top_form_fio" onblur='checkParams()'/>
<input type="text" name="phone" class="order_input" id="top_form_phone" onblur='checkParams()'/>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Отправить"/>
```

Сначала начал делать через событие `onblur`, но оно срабатывает, если фокус снят с `input`'ов, а у меня может и не быть такого.

Мой текущий вариант:

```
function checkParams() {
    var top_form_fio = $('#top_form_fio').val();
    var top_form_phone = $('#top_form_fio').val();
    if ((top_form_fio.length == 0) && (top_form_phone.length=0)) {
        //$('#bad_fio').fadeIn("slow"); 
        $('#top_form_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    }
    else {
        $('#top_form_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        //$('#bad_fio').fadeOut("slow");    
    }
}
```

Но работает неправильно. Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя использовать атрибуты для свойств!

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").on('change input paste', 'input', function(e) {
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', !$("#name").val() || !$("#phone").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type=text id=name name=name>
  <input type=text id=phone name=phone>
  <input type=submit id=submit value=Submit disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: Справедливости ради отмечу, что использовать атрибут вместо свойства можно.

Comment: @Regent, jQuery попытается правильно применить disabled true/false, но вот с checked уже начинаются глюки, когда реально чекнутость меняется только первый раз, например, а потом чекбокс перестаёт работать. Так что лучше всё-таки так не делать. Если есть свойство, то надо в него и писать, а не в атрибут.

Comment: Спору нет: использовать свойство вместо атрибута лучше, а в случае с `checked` ещё и критично. Но есть ли такие же проблемы с `disabled` хотя бы в старых браузерах, чтобы слово _"нельзя"_ было оправдано?

Comment: @Regent, насколько я помню, jQuery сам ресолвит значения true/false в сочетании с attr disabled, поэтому там проблем нет. Но в моём ответе не говорится, что нельзя именно с disabled, а говорится в целом про свойства. Те же checked и hidden - с ними проблемы запросто будут.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки в коде:

- Неправильный селектор для телефона. Должно быть: `var top_form_phone = $('#top_form_phone').val();`.
- Отсутствующий ID у кнопки. Должно быть: `<input type="submit" name="button" id="top_form_button" value="Отправить"/>`.
- Присваивание вместо сравнения. Должно быть: `top_form_phone.length == 0`.
- Нарушение логики работы из-за использования `&&` вместо `||`. Должно быть `(top_form_fio.length == 0 || top_form_phone.length == 0)`.
- Имеет смысл добавить `disabled="disabled"` кнопке по умолчанию, так как при загрузке страницы поля пустые.

**Итоговый код**:

```js
function checkParams() {
    var top_form_fio = $('#top_form_fio').val();
    var top_form_phone = $('#top_form_phone').val();
    if (top_form_fio.length == 0 || top_form_phone.length == 0) {
        $('#top_form_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    }
    else {
        $('#top_form_button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fio" class="order_input" id="top_form_fio" onblur='checkParams()'/>
<input type="text" name="phone" class="order_input" id="top_form_phone" onblur='checkParams()'/>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="top_form_button" value="Отправить" disabled="disabled"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Вариант** с использованием события `change` вместо `onblur` (несколько логичнее для проверки изменения значения), без inline JS и с использованием свойства вместо атрибута:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $texts = $('#top_form_fio, #top_form_phone');
    var $button = $('#top_form_button');  
    $texts.on("change", function() {
        var hasEmpty = $texts.filter(function() { return !$(this).val(); }).length > 0;
        $button.prop('disabled', hasEmpty);
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fio" class="order_input" id="top_form_fio" />
<input type="text" name="phone" class="order_input" id="top_form_phone" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="top_form_button" value="Отправить"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Если нужно** изменение состояния кнопки без потери фокуса элемента, можно использовать событие `keyup`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $texts = $('#top_form_fio, #top_form_phone');
    var $button = $('#top_form_button');  
    $texts.on("keyup", function() {
        var hasEmpty = $texts.filter(function() { return !$(this).val(); }).length > 0;
        $button.prop('disabled', hasEmpty);
    }).trigger('keyup');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fio" class="order_input" id="top_form_fio" />
<input type="text" name="phone" class="order_input" id="top_form_phone" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="top_form_button" value="Отправить"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```